# Ctrl 2 refactorings in Eclipse / STS

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, spring-tool-suite

I read on the blogs about Eclipse's quick assist shortcuts and went ahead to try them out, however only 2 out of the 4 work for me.

When I hit `Ctrl+2`, STS displays a hint with all 4 of them explained in the right bottom corner:

- **Ctrl+2, F**  - assign to field
- **Ctrl+2, L**  - assign to local variable
- **Ctrl+2, M**  - extract method
- **Ctrl+2, R**  - rename in a file

When I then hit a letter, the expected behavior only works for the last 2 (extract and rename), and not for the first 2 - F and L - to assign to a field or a local variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I see in Eclipse's General | Keys Preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See Eclipse Preferences General -> Keys page. Perhaps the first two key bindings are mapped to some other actions.

Comment: I added what I see there in the preferences